# ABCPDF font-face within my HTML not loading

Tags: css, abcpdf

I'm using the ABCPDF plugin to generate PDFs and I have declared a font directly within my HTML/CSS

```
                        @font-face{
                    font-family: FREE3OF9;
                    src: url('http://**myurl**/fonts/FREE3OF9.otf') format("opentype");
                    }

                    .barcodeStyle{
                    font-family:FREE3OF9;
                    font-size:40px;
                    text-align:center;
                    border:1px solid black;
                    padding:5px;
                    }
```

However it doesn't appear the font is getting picked up when the HTML is added to the document. Is there something else I need to do? I've verified the font path by rendering this in the browser which works correctly.

Comment: Try actually adding font, instead of URL reference: http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf/source/5-object_reference/doc/1-methods/addfont.htm

Comment: @Justinas do I still need to keep my CSS class and assign to html? The example above looks to be only applicable if you are adding the content directly from the ASP. Unfortunately I only want one specific div within my HTML contents to use this font.

Comment: Usually if you wish to use some font, even if for single letter, you need to tell PDF library, that "this is the font and save it for later".

Comment: Can you please confirm how this is done with a code sample?

Answer (score 1):

Web fonts are supported by the new ABCChrome HTML engine in ABCpdf 11. You can convert a URL (including a "file://" URI) using `Doc.AddImageUrl`, or an HTML string with `Doc.AddImageHtml`. And the [Paged HTML Example](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/4-examples/13-pagedhtml.htm) applies for HTML that may take up more than one PDF page.

If there is any latency/delay in accessing web fonts, you can make ABCpdf wait e.g.

```
    doc.HtmlOptions.RepaintDelay = 2000;
    doc.HtmlOptions.RepaintTimeout = 5000; // default
    int htmlID = doc.AddImageUrl(theURL);
```